# Play an audio some time after another audio has ended while in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, tizen

Currently I'm designing a Web application (game) on Tizen where I want to:

1. Display an image
2. Play an audio clip(around 15-17 seconds long)
3. Do nothing for 5 seconds
4. Play another audio clip(about 2-3 seconds)
5. Hide the image

These steps are to be performed in a loop (N times) in order. However, when I run my App on the emulator, it plays all the sounds to be played on step 2 together at the same time while the image is never visible.

Following is my Javascript function:

```
         function performTask(image, audioName) { //sending id for image and audio,  e.g.: performTask("img1", "aud1")

            // Show the image
            img = document.getElementById(image);
            if (img && img.style) {
                img.style.height = screen.height;
                img.style.width = screen.width;
                img.style.visibility = "visible";
            } else {
                console.log("exercise(): error in setting image");
            }
            // play the audio
            try {
                myAudio = document.getElementById(audioName);
                myAudio.play();
                myAudio.onended = function() {
                    timeOut();
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("exercise(): " + error.message);
            }
            // after 30 seconds, ring the bell!!
            try {
                console.log("playing bell");
                document.getElementById("bell").play();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("bell: " + error.message);
            }
            //hide image
            img.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
```

The timeOut() function:

```
        var timer = 5000;
        function timeOut() {
            if (timer > 0) {
                setTimeout(timeOut(), timer--);
            }
         }
```

The structure of the HTML page where this is called:

```
        ...
        <body onload="someFunc()"> <!-- this calls performTask() in a for-loop-->
        <p>
            <img src='images/image1.png' alt="pose1n12" id="img1" />
        .... 10 more such images
        </p>
        <p>
            <audio id="bell">
                <source src='audio/bell.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
            <audio id="aud1">
                <source src='audio/aud1.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>
        .... 10 more such clips
        </p>
```

**EDIT:** Adding the definition for someFunc()

```
     function someFunc() { 
        var a;
        image = ''; // select image at particular count
        audioName = ''; // select respective audio
        for (a = 1; a <= 12; a++) { // the asana tracker loop
            switch (a) { // assigns image & audio
            case 1:
                image = "img1n12";
                audioName = "1N12";
                break;
            ...... continues till case 12
            }
        }
        performTask(image, audioName);
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Set an Event Listener for when the audio has finished `document.getElementById("bell").addEventListener("ended",function(){//Some Code here to change the src});` You can have this run a function or call another function.

Comment: @NewToJS Tried it earlier, no luck

Comment: It would appear you have expanded on your question, maybe even complicated things. Didn't you want the to know how to play another audio file once the current audio has ended? I believe that was the original question...

Comment: @NewToJS I face the problem only when there is a looping. An individual call to the function works fine. Hence the part "in a for-loop"

Comment: This is why it's important for you to be clear about the issue in the first place, it will save you having to edit your question making the previous answers incorrect. I believe we call this "Planning your question" to avoid any confusion or misunderstanding. You wanted to know how to listen for the track ending to play another and this is why people have given you the answer to do exactly that. I wish you the best of luck with your question but I will not edit my answer each time you edit your question. Your question could be come a 'loop' of endless answering. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding there is an "ended" event fired when a sound has finished playing.

http://forestmist.org/blog/html5-audio-loops/

You could use this to make stage 2 trigger stage 3 and have stage 4 trigger stage 5.

Answer (score 0):

when playing the first audio, you should do every other step on the call back onended, and if you need to wait again some other time, you need to pass the call back to the setTimeout, the following code is a bit simplified :

```
// on Global scope 
var audioName = "something";
var img = document.getElementById("image_id");

showImage ();
playAudio(audioName, function () {
   playBell (); 
   hideImage ();
});
```

Now the functions definition would be like this :

```
function showImage () {
    if (img && img.style) {
        img.style.height = screen.height;
        img.style.width = screen.width;
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        console.log("exercise(): error in setting image");
    }
}
function playAudio (audioName, callback) {
    try {
        myAudio = document.getElementById(audioName);
        myAudio.play();
        myAudio.onended = function() {
            setTimeout(callback, 5000); // after 5 seconds
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("exercise(): " + error.message);
    }
}
function playBell () {
     try {
         console.log("playing bell");
        document.getElementById("bell").play();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("bell: " + error.message);
    }
}
function hideImage() {
    img.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have two examples of **addEventListener('ended')**. This event listener should work fine for what you are asking.

> **First Method:** Calls another function `ChangeSrc()` and uses the same player.

Method one will get the player by id, tell the player to play and add the event listener. This will listen of the ended event then call ChangeSrc(). When ChangeSrc is called the eventlistener is removed and the player src is changed to the next track and then told to play.

**HTML:**

```
<b>Method One</b><button onclick="MethodOne()">Start</button><br>
<img id="DemoImg" src="sample1.png"/><br/>
<audio id="DemoAud" controls>
  <source src='sample1.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function MethodOne(){
    var a=document.getElementById("DemoImg");
    var b=document.getElementById("DemoAud");
    b.play();
    b.addEventListener('ended',ChangeSrc,false);
}
function ChangeSrc(){
    var a=document.getElementById("DemoImg");
    var b=document.getElementById("DemoAud");
    b.removeEventListener("ended",ChangeSrc);
        a.src="sample2.png";
        b.src="sample2.mp3";
        b.play();
}
```

---

> **Second Method:** Uses one function and two players *(Like your source code does)*

This method is very much like the first method but had the function in the eventlistener, this will tell the other player to play as this function will only run when the first audio clip has ended. This will also display the container for the image/player.

**HTML**

```
<b>Method Two</b><button onclick="MethodTwo()">Start</button><br>
<div id="Demo2"  class="DemoBlock">
<img id="DemoImg2" src="sample1.png"/><br/>
<audio id="DemoAud2" controls>
  <source src='sample1.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div><div id="Demo3" class="DemoBlock">
<img id="DemoImg3" src="sample2.png"/><br/>
<audio id="DemoAud3" controls>
  <source src='sample2.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function MethodTwo(){
    var a=document.getElementById("DemoAud2");
    var b=document.getElementById("DemoAud3");
    a.play();
    a.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    document.getElementById("Demo3").style.display="inline-block";
    b.play();
    },false);   
}
```

---

This Exmaple is just to show you two different methods of the using the eventlistener, the rest is down to you to integrate this into your existing source code.

---

> **Demo Source Code**

```js
function MethodOne(){
    var a=document.getElementById("DemoImg");
    var b=document.getElementById("DemoAud");
    b.play();
    b.addEventListener('ended',ChangeSrc,false);
}
function ChangeSrc(){
    var a=document.getElementById("DemoImg");
    var b=document.getElementById("DemoAud");
    b.removeEventListener("ended",ChangeSrc);
        a.src="https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample2.png";
        b.src="https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample2.mp3";
        b.play();
}
function MethodTwo(){
    var a=document.getElementById("DemoAud2");
    var b=document.getElementById("DemoAud3");
    a.play();
    a.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    document.getElementById("Demo3").style.display="inline-block";
    b.play();
    },false);   
}
```

```css
.DemoBlock{display:inline-block;}
#Demo3{display:none;}
```

```html
<b>Method One</b><button onclick="MethodOne()">Start</button><br>
<img id="DemoImg" src="https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample1.png"/><br/>
<audio id="DemoAud" controls>
  <source src='https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample1.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<hr/>
<b>Method Two</b><button onclick="MethodTwo()">Start</button><br>
<div id="Demo2"  class="DemoBlock">
<img id="DemoImg2" src="https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample1.png"/><br/>
<audio id="DemoAud2" controls>
  <source src='https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample1.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div><div id="Demo3" class="DemoBlock">
<img id="DemoImg3" src="https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample2.png"/><br/>
<audio id="DemoAud3" controls>
  <source src='https://coded4u.co.uk/SO/28831485/sample2.mp3' type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!